# How Do I Receive an Array of Pointers in a JNA Structure?

Tags: jna

Here is the definition of the structure in the C API I'm using:

```
typedef struct {
    int nADs;
    int** mPIAD;
} LSO;

int CalcTheValue(int numMats;
                 LSO* returnValue);
```

mPIAD is "actually" a 2-D array of which nADS is the first dimension and the second dimension is numMats.

Currently I have the JNA defined as follows:

```
public static class t_LdvSummaryOutput_v1 extends Structure {
    public int numADs;
    public Pointer mPIADs; // int**
}
```

Using the Eclipse debugger I see the data in mPIADS is not what I am expecting.  I should be getting single digit integers as return values but instead I'm seeing very large integer values.

Should I declare mPIADs as `public Pointer[] mPIADs`?

Comment: Try [`output.mPIADs.getPointerArray(0, output.numADs)`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getPointerArray-long-) to the array of pointers.

Comment: Thank you cubrr!  Using your recommendation I am now able to access the returned values correctly!

Comment: Oh, that's great! I'll add it as an answer then!

Answer (score 0):

Since the pointer is actually an array of pointers, you could use `Pointer.getPointerArray`:

```
// t_LdvSummaryOutput_v1 output;
Pointer[] mPIADs = output.mPIADs.getPointerArray(0, output.numADs)
```